# How to pass dynamic parameter to the query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, dynamic

Here is my code:

```
$param2 = $val2 = "";
if ($myCondition){
    $parm2 = ", param2 = ?";
    $val2 = "something";
}

$stmt = $dbh_conn->prepare("UPDATE myTable SET param1 = ? $param2 WHERE param3 = ?");
$stmt->execute([$val1, $val2, $val3]);
```

My code works when that condition is `true`. How can I handle that when that's `false` ?

Comment: Build an `$array` you pass to `execute` in the same conditions. So if the IF doesn't happen, then the array is missing a value.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I knew that before asking this question, your solution is boring, since in reality there are 12 parameters `:-(` .. I'm looking for a clean approach. But apparently there isn't any better approach. Thank you anyway. I guess I have to go with your idea ..

Comment: Boring? Cleaner? Hehe... I'm sure you could come up with something... just put your "outside the box" cap on! But what u_mulder has, is pretty much what most people do with it.

Comment: Ternary operator?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I don't get your point...

Comment: @MartinAJ if you had a default value set from inside a ternary operator, that would make it so that it would not fail in any case. Or, maybe I'm not grasping the question.

Comment: Just be happy you are using PDO, and not trying this in mysqli... it gets much more messy ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code to start:

```
$params = ['param1 = ?'];
$values = [$param1];
if ($myCondition){
    $params[] = 'param2 = ?'
    $values = [$param2];
}
$values[] = $param3;

$stmt = $dbh_conn->prepare("UPDATE myTable SET " . implode(', ', $params)  . " WHERE param3 = ?");
$stmt->execute($values);
```

You can modify it as you want, but the main idea is to gather all values that will be updated in array and then implode this array to a string.

Answer (score 3):

```
$param2 = $val2 = "";
if ($myCondition){
    $parm2 = ", param2 = ?";
    $val2 = "something"; 
    $stmt = $dbh_conn->prepare("UPDATE myTable SET param1 = ? $param2 WHERE param3 = ?");
    $stmt->execute([$val1, $val2, $val3]);
} else {
    $stmt = $dbh_conn->prepare("UPDATE myTable SET param1 = ? WHERE param3 = ?");
    $stmt->execute([$val1, $val3]);
}
```

Comment: it was helpful buddy

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is:

```
if ($myCondition){
$stmt = $dbh_conn->prepare("UPDATE myTable SET param1 = ?, param2 = ? WHERE param3 = ?");
$stmt->execute([$val1, "something", $val3]);
} else {
    $stmt = $dbh_conn->prepare("UPDATE myTable SET param1 = ? WHERE param3 = ?");
$stmt->execute([$val1, $val3]);
}
```